# NSPredicate SUBQUERY for 1 to many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, objective-c, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I'm trying to build an NSPredicate to satisfy a given relationship. My data model has the following: `University -> College -> Classrooms - ClassroomType`

- A university object has 1 to many colleges.
- A college object has 1 to many classrooms.
- Each classroom has a given classroom type with a specified property
  i'm interested in.

That property is called `typeDescription` I want to build a query that can give me all universities that have a typeDescription equal to the value "computerlab". The objects that I have available to me are a list of Universities. I'm pretty sure that I'll need to construct an `NSPredicate` `SUBQUERY` but I'm not quite sure no how to build this to satisfy my requirements. If anyone has any input on the right way to build this query it would be much appreciated.

Comment: any sample of result you want from table given sample too.. need more details

Comment: Why do you only have a list of universities? You can run the query on whatever entity you want (and map to the desired result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one-to-many-to-many relationships, you need to nest two SUBQUERY clauses:

```
NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(colleges, $c, SUBQUERY($c.classrooms, $room, $room.classroomType.typeDescription == %@).@count > 0).@count > 0","computer lab")
```

Comment: One of the to-many relationship can use `ANY`: `"SUBQUERY(colleges, $c, ANY $c.classrooms.classroomType.typeDescription == %@).@count > 0","computer lab"`.